# How can I connect my sql (workbench) to mysql server (bluehost) to activate a CRM system?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I've tried using sql workbench to connect to mysql bluehost database and then migrate the data I have in the tables to the tables on my bluehost server, so I've created a subdomain to upload the CRM zip file and install the CRM on it.

So I've tried multiple ways to connect them together, created a new IP on bluehost to connect it to the workbench but it never gets connected I am not sure why, I've tried connecting the sql workbench to the localhost, it worked but I can't get to upload the zip folder (42mb) to the localhost and install it to make the CRM work and then migrate the data of the clients and customers on the CRM database.

my workbench is now connected to my localhost (root) but it gives me connection warning, not supported even though I've tried the ctrl+R for reverse engineer database and it worked at first to create the connection but then it does not run smoothly, it is still not supported.

So I want to either be able to upload the zip file to the localhost to install the crm and then migrate the data to it, or be able to connect my bluehost server to the sql workbench I have on my pc (knowing that the CRM is already installed on my bluehost just missing the data of the clients)

Comment: Since you're using MySQL Workbench, I'm not sure why you've tagged this question with phpMyAdmin, is there something I'm missing about your question?

Comment: I am actually checking the connectivity between the 3 of them, comparing the data in the workbench, the SQL management studio and phpMyAdmin, but that is not the main issue, it does not allow me to migrate the flat file (import it) to workbench stating that "the file is not loaded properly, please check the file and try again", tried changing the code of the page (from latin 1 to utf-8) but it does not allow me to finish exporting the data in that case from sql management studio. @IsaacBennetch